# Gentoo and GPT Grub support

Tags: linux, raid, gentoo, grub

Grub seems to support GPT, or so it says, there is a patch for it, however when i try to boot after installing grub into the active boot partition (ext2) it starts to boot and before grub loads any stage 1.5 stuff it dies and hangs, got 1 big raid array on an Areca card and need to be able to boot from this, dont care how, grub, lilo, whatever, just need to work out a way to boot from the GPT drive. Don't care if I have to nuke the partitions either, just need this stupid thing to work *sigh*

BTW, areca is FAAAAAAAAST :) just wish i read up on this before the initial installation

originally it was set to msdos label on the filesystem before i changed it to gpt (the system was working, just couldnt use past 2tb (4.5tb total)) then i rescued the partitions in parted and they mount fine from a livecd, im curious if that isnt the cause of the problem but doubtful it is at the same time. Suggestions welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this HOWTO?
[link](http://www.wensley.org.uk/gpt)


Also you might want to try this [patch](http://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=178586).